# fire Notification on Web service Result.

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

my requirement is to fire notification message like popup in iPad, message i am getting from web service. i am calling web service after certain time interval and only if user to be notified then only i have to show notification.
my code is not working, i want like pop up. my code is below:

```
    - (void)scheduleNotificationWithInterval:(NSString *)Notificationmsg
    {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];

    UILocalNotification *localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotification == nil)
        return;

    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate date];
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"MyApp!";
    localNotification.repeatInterval = nil;
    localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:NSLocalizedString(Notificationmsg, nil)];
    localNotification.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View Details", nil);
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    /*
    NSDictionary *infoDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Object 1", @"Key 1", @"Object 2", @"Key 2", nil];
    localNotification.userInfo = infoDict;*/

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:localNotification];

   }
```

Please help me.

Comment: Local notification will be displayed if your app is not running in foreground

Comment: my client requirement is i have to call web service , which will return me notification message to be shown so this will happen only in foreground mode, than i need to fire notification like pop up. i do not want ant time or anything .. only if web service return me message i have to send notification to user…pop up way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Your fire localnotification and app is open Active state it will call this method and if app is in background mode it will show notification i.e what you style you have set for your app.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {

    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        NSLog(@"lcoal:%@",[notification userInfo]);

        UIAlertView *al=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Challenge gehaald!" message:@"Gefeliciteerd, je hebt deze bonus challenge succesvol afgerond." delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [al show];

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
  -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification{
        // I recieved a notification
    }
```

put this method in Appdelegate class.